# how to solve "Use Of Undeclared Type"

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am following this tutorial, and when I used the code mentioned in it, i got the errors shown in the image-1 below, I do not why i am getting these errors despite i am using the same code

I googled how to fix that error, and some posts suggested importing the UKIT class, and I did that but the error still there

please let me know how to fix it

**image-1**:

[image]

Comment: `UITableViewDataSource` not `UITableViewSource`, and that's Swift, not Objective-C

Comment: You need to write UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource. While you have written  UITableViewSource. Which is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `UITableViewDataSource` instead `UITableViewSource`

And add the delegates and datasource

```
//MARK: - Table Delegates

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1;
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10;
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let cellId: NSString = "cellSearch"
        let cell: customCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId as String)! as! customCell

        return cell

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {



    }
```

Comment: ok..i did as you suggested..now I am getting this error:Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'

Comment: add all the required tableview delegates

Comment: is there a short cut in Xcode to add these methods?

Comment: autocomplete options are there.

Answer (score 0):

you have misspelled UITableViewSource its actually UITableViewDataSource,

add the datasource methods,

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = demoTableVIew.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = "CELL NUMBER : \(indexPath.row)"

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: ok..i did as you suggested..now I am getting this error:Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'

Comment: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = demoTableVIew.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = "CELL NUMBER : \(indexPath.row)"
     
        return cell
    }